# Unfamiliar syntax in a method

Tags: ruby, methods, boolean

So I'm working through the Koans ruby exercises and am unfamiliar with the syntax in the block for this method. Can somebody explain to me what is described in here starting with the 2nd line? Thanks !!!

```
    def test_nil_is_an_object
        assert_equal true, nil.is_a?(Object), "Unlike NULL in other languages"
    end
```

Comment: I don't know if your question relates to the absence of optional parentheses around the three arguments to the method, `assert_equal`, or to the purpose of the `assert_equal` method.  If the latter, see, for example, this [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing) for an explanation of "unit testing" in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks Cary that article helped. I didn't understand either the optional parentheses or the purpose of the assert_equal method so that cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit parentheses in ruby, so it is basically an [`assert_equal`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_equal) call. It can be rewritten as following:

```
assert_equal(true, nil.is_a?(Object), "Unlike NULL in other languages")
```

Two forms are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciate it.